# how to select one item of each category from a table where a category is entered multple times

Tags: php, mysql

`Product table`

`_________________________________`

`|id  |name  |category  |date    |`

`---------------------------------`

`|1   |p1    |1         |13586486|`

`---------------------------------`

`|2   |p2    |2         |13586445|`

`---------------------------------`

`|3   |p3    |1         |13567456|`

`---------------------------------`

`|5   |p5    |3         |13586422|`

`--------------------------------`

`|6   |p6    |3         |13586678|`

`--------------------------------`

`|7   |p7    |1         |13586495|`

`--------------------------------`
this somehow my table looks, now my question is how to select one product of each category which is the latest in that category, is this possible in a single query?
i tried so many things but its too lengthy... help please

Comment: can you assume that highest product id in category means that it is latest or you prefer to check by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p1.* from Product p1 left join Product p2 on p1.category = p2.category and p1.id < p2.id where p2.id is null
```

This will give you latest record based on latest id as there is no other field by which I can find time of added record.

**Edit**
changed `select * from` to `select p1.* from`, it will not return extra empty columns from table p2.

Comment: i tested with 4-5 dummy entries of categories,it did the job thank you buddy, m doing a small correction for ignoring extra empty columns .. thank you so much..

Comment: it will take very less time bcoz I didn't use sub query.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (if you want it per the highest date):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Product AS t1
    JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
        MAX(t.date) AS date,
        t.category
    FROM 
        Product AS t
    GROUP BY
        t.category
    )
    AS maxCat 
    ON maxCat.date=t1.date
    AND maxCat.category=t1.category
```

If you want it by the highest product id then you can do this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Product AS t1
    JOIN 
    (
    SELECT 
        MAX(t.id) AS id,
        t.category
    FROM 
        Product AS t
    GROUP BY
        t.category
    )
    AS maxCat 
    on maxCat.id=t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

In Sql server you may use this:

```
with productWithRows as(
select row_number() over (partition by category order by date desc) as rownb,*
from product
) as productWithRows,
select * from productWithRows where rownb=1
```

Comment: The OPs question is not in sql server. So this is relevant why?

Comment: i use mysql. i have tagged only mysql